# Programmatically editing odoo website content

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

Where do odoo website module save content? Like menus, banner images and other text and html?
I actually want to see where menus of mega-menu store in database(table name) how they render on the website. Observing this I want to add some html while rendering those menu items.

Answer (score 0):

- pages store in website_page
- menus (mega menu also) store in website_menu
- redirect links store in website_rewrite
- attachments (banners, images) store in ir_attachment
- view of pages store in ir_ui_view

The way odoo render something into html form is that you create a xml form, then store it in ir_ui_view. When some route loaded and need a view, after all view inheritance, odoo gets a final xml form then create a corresponding html view.